# Oracle self join copying column value over different values in the same column

Tags: sql, oracle, join, self-join

I have some near-duplicate data that I'm trying to clean up. I'm doing a self-join to find records where all but one of the columns are equal so I can find the best of those duplicates to delete from the table. The problem I'm running into is that although the number records is correct, I'm only seeing one of the id column values repeated over and over. When I look at all of the values associated with this user, there's only one occurrence of the id column value that's being repeated.

I know that's not completely clear, so hopefully this will help.

```
Id1    ID2    AnotherColumn    AnotherColumn2
---------------------------------------------

1      345       "a"                "bd"
2      345       "a"                "bd"
3      345       "a"                "bd"
4      345       "a"                "bd"
5      345       "a"                "bd"
```

What I want to get back is everything exactly as you see it in this dummy table. What I'm getting is this:

```
Id1    ID2    AnotherColumn    AnotherColumn2
---------------------------------------------

1      345       "a"                "bd"
1      345       "a"                "bd"
1      345       "a"                "bd"
1      345       "a"                "bd"
1      345       "a"                "bd"
```

The query I am using looks like this:

```
select A.Id1, A.ID2, A.AnotherColumn, A.AnotherColumn2
from dummy_table A, dummy_table B
where A.ID2 = B.ID2
AND A.Id1 <> B.Id1
AND A.AnotherColumn = B.AnotherColumn
AND A.AnotherColumn2 = B.AnotherColumn2
```

What I would like to know is why the value of Id1 is being copied onto the other rows instead of the original Id1 value actually showing up.

I need to have a list of the ids out of this table that match these criteria, because I will have to delete them out of the original table which contains other records that do not match these criteria that need to be left untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your query, I end up with 20 rows; 4 for each id1 value (which is the same as 4 x 5, as you're effectively doing a cross join, only excluding the rows where a.id1 = b.id1).

```
with dummy_table as (select 1 id1, 345 ID2, 'a' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual union all
                     select 2 id1, 345 ID2, 'a' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual union all
                     select 3 id1, 345 ID2, 'a' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual union all
                     select 4 id1, 345 ID2, 'a' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual union all
                     select 5 id1, 345 ID2, 'a' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual)
select A.Id1, A.ID2, A.AnotherColumn, A.AnotherColumn2
from dummy_table A, dummy_table B
where A.ID2 = B.ID2
AND A.Id1 <> B.Id1
AND A.AnotherColumn = B.AnotherColumn
AND A.AnotherColumn2 = B.AnotherColumn2
order by 1, 2, 3, 4


       ID1        ID2 ANOTHERCOLUMN ANOTHERCOLUMN2
---------- ---------- ------------- --------------
         1        345 a             bd            
         1        345 a             bd            
         1        345 a             bd            
         1        345 a             bd            
         2        345 a             bd            
         2        345 a             bd            
         2        345 a             bd            
         2        345 a             bd            
         3        345 a             bd            
         3        345 a             bd            
         3        345 a             bd            
         3        345 a             bd            
         4        345 a             bd            
         4        345 a             bd            
         4        345 a             bd            
         4        345 a             bd            
         5        345 a             bd            
         5        345 a             bd            
         5        345 a             bd            
         5        345 a             bd
```

However, I wonder if you're after something like:

```
with dummy_table as (select 1 id1, 345 ID2, 'a' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual union all
                     select 2 id1, 345 ID2, 'a' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual union all
                     select 3 id1, 345 ID2, 'a' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual union all
                     select 4 id1, 345 ID2, 'a' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual union all
                     select 5 id1, 345 ID2, 'a' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual union all
                     select 6 id1, 345 ID2, 'b' AnotherColumn, 'bd' AnotherColumn2 from dual)
select id1,
       id2,
       anothercolumn,
       anothercolumn2
from   (select id1,
               id2,
               anothercolumn,
               anothercolumn2,
               count(*) over (partition by id2, anothercolumn, anothercolumn2) cnt
        from   dummy_table)
where  cnt > 1;

       ID1        ID2 ANOTHERCOLUMN ANOTHERCOLUMN2
---------- ---------- ------------- --------------
         1        345 a             bd            
         2        345 a             bd            
         3        345 a             bd            
         4        345 a             bd            
         5        345 a             bd
```

It's possible you don't need ananlytic functions at all - to remove all rows except the one with the lowest id1, you could do something like:

```
delete from dummy_table
where id1 not in (select min(id1) from dummy_table group by id2, anothercolumn, anothercolumn2);
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something really similar to the first option you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select min(A.id) over (partition by A.ID2, A.AnotherColumn, A.AnotherColumn2) as id,
       A.id2, A.AnotherColumn, A.AnotherColumn2
from dummy_table A;
```

This returns the minimum `id` for combinations of columns in the `partition by` clause.

Comment: How would that work with a table similar to the one I posted, but with multiple sets of that kind of data along with data that doesn't fit that criteria? I want to choose out the data that matches these criteria and then choose the max of the Id1 column as the record to keep and delete the rest. Sorry, I'm not familiar with partitions at all.